# С++ Разработать класс, в который расположить столбцы динамического массива в порядке возрастания значений элементов k-ой строки

Tags: c++

Создаётся динамический двумерный массив.
Затем заполняется случайными значениями.
С клавиатуры вводится k. k - строка которая сортируется по возрастанию, по принципу сортировки строки k, сортируются остальные столбцы всех остальных строк. То есть во время обмена столбцов строки k методом пузырька, необходимо менять также как и в строке k столбцы других строк.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SortRow.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SortRow::SortRow()
{
}

void SortRow::sortarr()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int A, B, K;
    cout << "Введите количество строк двумерного массива" << endl;
    cin >> A;
    int** Mass = new int*[A];
    cout << "Введите количество строк двумерного массива" << endl;
    cin >> B;
    for (int i = 0; i<B; i++) Mass[i] = new int[B];
    cout << "Введите строку по значениям которой, необходимо рассортировать стобцы" << endl;
    cin >> K;
    //ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ!
    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < B; j++)
        {
            Mass[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << Mass[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    //КОНЕЦ ЗАПОЛНЕНИЯ!
    //СОРТИРОВКА!
    for (int k = 0; k < A; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < B; i++)
        {
            for (int j = A - 1; j > i; j--)
                if (Mass[K-1][j] < Mass[K-1][j - 1])
                {

                    int tmp = Mass[k][j];
                    Mass[k][j] = Mass[k][j - 1];
                    Mass[k][j - 1] = tmp;

                }
            cout << Mass[k][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    //КОНЕЦ СОРТИРОВКИ!
}




SortRow::~SortRow()
{
}
```

Получается только рассортировать строку k. А надо на основе её обменов столбиками, таким образом рассортировать другие столбцы, всех остальных строк.

Comment: А стоит ли? Я бы создал массив пар - значение и индекс в исходной строке, рассортировал бы по значению, а потом уже в соответствии с индексами расставил столбцы.

Comment: Как можно это сделать? Одномерным, записать туда индексы. а дальше...

Comment: Каждый элемент такого одномерного вектора - например, структура с полями значения и индекса в исходном массиве. Или объект `std::pair`.

Comment: в вашем вопросе   я прочитал разработать класс, но вы даже не пытались это сделать. Так или иначе, я советую изучить существующий класс  std::valarray.  После вы сможете легко создать матрицы и также легко манипулировать ими. Я не полностью понел что вам нужно, а то мог бы вам кинуть пример решения. Я имел ввиду, что вы пытались решить проблему одной функцией, которая является единственным членом класса ( в этом не вижу никакого смысла и пользы)

Comment: Вообщем я само задание как оно есть описал в заголовке, а так когда ниже описываю то бред какой-то. До меня не доходит что от меня требуется сделать..

Answer (score 0):

```
// ConsoleApplication21.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Swap(int Arr[], int x, int y)
{
    int t = Arr[x];
    Arr[x] = Arr[y];
    Arr[y] = t;
}
void BubbleSort(int Arr[], int N)
{
    bool process;
    do {
        process = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<N - 1; ++i)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            if (Arr[j] < Arr[i])
            {
                Swap(Arr, i, j);
                process = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (process);
}
int SimpleSearch(int Arr[], int N, int Search)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
        if (Arr[i] == Search)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
const int m = 3, n = 3, null = -5;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[m][n], earr[m][n];
    for (int i = 0; i<m; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; ++j)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand()% 100;
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Vvedite index k: ";
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int ark[n], art[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        ark[i] = arr[k][i];
        art[i] = arr[k][i];
    }
    BubbleSort(ark, n);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        int k = SimpleSearch(art, n, ark[i]);
        art[k] = null;
        for (int j = 0; j<m; ++j)
            earr[j][i] = arr[j][k];
    }
    cout << "\nOtsortirovannyi massiv:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<m; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; ++j)
            cout << earr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```